# Event handlers don't work in js

Tags: javascript, events

Why do my event handlers not work in my javascript function.If it's the wrong way to access a button event handler inside a js function than how to do it correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function cl(){
    var button = document.getElementById('but');
    button.onclick = function (){
        alert('this works');
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value = "click" id = "but">
</body>
```

Comment: You aren't actually ever calling the cl() function are you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrapped the event handler method into another method. Call your method and it will work

```
cl();
```

However, I'd rather initialise the scripts on that page simply by waiting for the document to load:

```
  function init() {
      button.onclick = function (){
          alert('this works');
      }
  }
  document.onload = init();
```

I'd move that script tag containing the JS code after the body tag, just to make it unobtrusive, so that the code should look like:

```
...
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" id="but">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var button = document.getElementById('but');
        button.onclick = function (){
            alert('this works');
        }
    }
    document.onload = init();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help to tell the OP **when** to add the listener (e.g. place script after the element, use *window.onload*).

Comment: Also, cl isn't an event-handler. It's simply a function.

Comment: Thank you both @RobG and Alexandr for the heads up, I have updated my answer.

Comment: this worked on jsfiddle, but doesn't want to in a browser.What can cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `cl` function is not beeing called since the function is not called anywhere.

Either you remove the function declaration like:

```
function cl(){
   document.getElementById('but').onclick = function() {
   alert('fdsfsdf');
};
```

Or you call the function to go into the code by calling `cl();`:

```
cl();    
function cl(){
   document.getElementById('but').onclick = function() {
   alert('fdsfsdf');
};
```

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PKntA/)